# Can I jump to symbol in Eclipse similar to Sublime Text 2?

Tags: eclipse, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2, symbols

Is there a way to quickly jump to a given symbol in Eclipse similar to how it's possible in Sublime Text 2? In Sublime Text 2 it's possible using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> shortcut (Goto Anything) and then typing `@` and a symbol name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible using *Globals Browser* which by default is accessible with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Comment: This only seems to work for Types - is there a version that works for any symbol (fields, methods, etc)?